# Creating new instances + hosts file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible

So I have been trying to create an Ansible playbook which creates a new instance to GCP and create a test file inside that instance. I've been using this [example project from Github as template](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-video-demo-ansible). In this example project, there is ansible_hosts -file which contains this host:

```
[gce_instances]
myinstance[1:4]
```

but I don't have any idea what it is doing actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fragment your provided is Ansible technology and not actually related to anything GCP specific.  This is a good reference doc:  [Working with Inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html).

At a high level,

```
[gce_instances]
myinstance[1:4]
```

the hosts file defines the machine identities against which Ansible is to execute against.  With the hosts file, you can define groups of hosts to allow you to apply ansible playbooks to subsets of hosts at a time.

In the example, a group is created that is called `gce_instances`.  There is nothing special or magic about the name.  It isn't any kind of key word/phrase special to our story.

Within a group, we specify the hostnames that we wish to work against.

The example given is a wild-card specifier and simply short-hand for:

```
[gce_instances]
myinstance1
myinstance2
myinstance3
myinstance4
```